# python : threads do not work properly in daemon

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing simple script that will check for SSH connection, and I cannot understand, why it hangs on one thread.

```python
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, hostname ):
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)
         self.hostname = hostname
    def run(self):
        return self.doSSH(self.hostname)

    def doSSH(self,hostname):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((hostname, 22))
        result = s.recv(1024)
        if re.findall(r'^SSH.+?SSH.+',result) :
            return "Up"
        else :
            return "Down"

def main():
    q = Queue.Queue()
    completeHostlist = ["host1","host2","google.com","host3"]
    for hostname in completeHostlist:
        thread =  myThread(hostname)
        thread.daemon = True
        q.put_nowait(thread.run())
    q.get_nowait()
```

I don't understand why this script hangs at google.com? I would be expecting it to spawn daemon thread and continue with host3. As soon it finish host3 it has to kill thread with Google and return results. What I did wrong ?

I already figured out about run() and start(). Anyway this is not working as expected, after all host[1-3] threads was started, script stuck at thread with google , waiting it to end. Should it be kill it at the end of the script ?

Should i be using multiprocessing instead of multithreading , to spawn separate process for each host?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `main()` should not have been indented

Comment: please, don't add answers into the *question* text, you could post your own answer if you like and/or accept other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `.run()` method directly for any thread. As [@Sorin said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20406342/4279) call `thread.start()` instead.

You don't need to define a new thread class, a function is enough in this case:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def is_ssh_up(result_queue, hostname, port=22):
    # try to connect here
    # ...
    # write results
    result_queue.put((hostname, True)) # Up

def main():
    q = Queue()
    hosts = ["host1", "host2", "google.com", "host3"]

    for hostname in hosts: # start worker threads
        t = Thread(target=is_ssh_up, args=[q, hostname])
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for _ in hosts: # collect results
        hostname, is_up = q.get()
        print("%s is %s" % (hostname, "Up" if is_up else "Down"))
```

Or you could use a thread pool:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def is_ssh_up(hostname, port=22):
    # try to connect here
    # ...
    # return results
    return hostname, is_up

hosts = ["host1", "host2", "google.com", "host3"]
pool = ThreadPool(20) # limit number of concurrent connections to 20
for hostname, is_up in pool.imap_unordered(is_ssh_up, hosts):
    status = "Up" if is_up else "Down" if is_up is not None else "Unknown"
    print("%s status is %s" % (hostname, status))
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, i already figured out about run() and start(). Anyway this is not working as expected, after all host[1-3] threads was started, script stuck at thread with google , waiting it to end.  Should it be kill it at the end of the script ?

Comment: @DanielGurianov: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20404226/edit) and add a minimal complete code example that shows the problem, include input, output, traceback (if any). Use `ThreadPool`-based code, it is simpler, less places to break. Don't forget to catch exceptions in `is_ssh_up()`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Sebastian. I need to close this one , cause  i need completely re-phrase my question in order to ask for what i need.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you do `q.put_nowait(thread.run())`. That immediately runs the ssh thing on the current thread. You need to call thread specific method to start the thread. You need to call `thread.start()`.

Not sure what you're doing with the Queue.